# Prove $\text{div(rot}X)=0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, differential-forms

Prove $\text{div(rot}X)=0$, $\forall X\in  \mathcal{X(\mathbb{R^n})}$

$X$ is a vector field on $\mathbb{R^n}$, $\omega$ it's a form

$X\mapsto \omega \mapsto d\omega \mapsto *(d\omega)=\text{rot}X$

(problem 14 from do Carmo's differential forms.)

---

$\text{rot}X$ is an $(n-2)$-form which maintains coefficients, so $\text{rot}X= \sum_I a_Idx^I$, here is where I stuck I don't know how to compute the $\text{div}$ of an $(n-2)$-form.

For example, in $\mathbb{R^4}$ $\text{rot}X=a_{12}dx^1\wedge dx^2+a_{13}dx^1\wedge dx^3+a_{14}dx^1\wedge dx^4+a_{23}dx^2\wedge dx^3+a_{24}dx^2\wedge dx^4+a_{34}dx^3\wedge dx^4$
how do I compute $\text{div(rot}X)$ ?

Comment: What is $\operatorname{div}$ of a $n-2$ form?

Comment: What chapter of Differential Forms and Applications? I'm leafing through the book and don't see this Problem 14.

In any case usually I've seen the divergence expressed as the one-form codifferential $\star d \star$ (and this is the form it takes in e.g. the Divergence Theorem). So I don't know what's going on here. Are you sure $n$ is arbitrary and you're not looking at $n=3$ in particular?

Comment: @user7530 my instructor must have made a typo, for $ n=3 $ we have  $rotX=a_1dx+a_2dy+a_3dz$ and $div(rotX)=\frac{\partial a_1}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial a_2}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial a_3}{\partial y}$, why is that zero ?

Comment: @user7530 never mind the coefficients $a_i$ containing partial derivatives and its all working out.